# git bisect with feature branches / later commits are needed to build

Tags: git

I'm trying to bisect a bug in the master branch, but the code from my feature branch is needed for my project/test to build.
I've rebased my feature branch against the (buggy) master branch and noticed that a commit from the last few days in master has introduced a bug. When I do `git bisect bad` in my feature branch and `git bisect good some-commit-in-master-last-week`, git checks out a point in master - but now I can't compile and test if the problem still persists, because the patches in my feature branch are missing.
Can I get git to only revert an individual patch, and then going back to HEAD?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to run

```
git diff master feature | patch -p1
```

after each step.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the current checked-out commit, at each bisect point, in any way you like; just don't make a new commit from it, and then `git reset --hard HEAD` to undo the change after testing.  See the example of merging in the `hot-fix` branch in the [git bisect documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html).  This allows fully automated bisect testing (again, see docs).