# Can git bisect ignore folders, for instance test folders?

Tags: git, version-control, git-bisect

Let say I've previously set up a super-swish test framework for a legacy system. That is feature A existed **long** before the test for feature A. Feature B, C and D come along and without us realising, at some point break the test for feature A.

We want to find out which of  the features did that.

Now I want to run:

```
git bisect <bad> <good>
git run ./swish_test_suite.sh
```

The issue is that the code files that test feature A came in between `<bad>` and `<good>`. I've tried just manually extracting out the code, but then various configurations, and paths to test data break (fragile code?).

Is there a way to tell `git bisect` to ignore a folder? I can imagine that going horribly wrong sometimes, but I'm guessing that might be easier than alternatives.

It's not solved here [How can I ignore a directory when doing a Git bisect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37197491/1075247) as that covers build folders, where the solution is to remove them from the repo, but *I want to keep my tests commited!*

This [git bisect with feature branches / later commits are needed to build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19800910/1075247) is a little different too, as I'm not using patches or *feature* branches (should I?) Also the solutions seem to just be for manually running it, not `git bisect run`ning it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this, write your test script in such a way that it adds stuff that you need in each step. The `git help bisect` manual has an example which you might be able to tweak to your needs. I.e., where that example does a `git merge hotfix`, do whatever you need to get the test files you require. Depending on the situation, a merge may not be what you're looking for, but you might cherry-pick your tests from somewhere, or simply copy them to some other directory beforehand (before the bisect operation) and copy them in with `cp`.

```
   ·   Automatically bisect with temporary modifications (hot-fix):

           $ cat ~/test.sh
           #!/bin/sh

           # tweak the working tree by merging the hot-fix branch
           # and then attempt a build
           if      git merge --no-commit hot-fix &&
                   make
           then
                   # run project specific test and report its status
                   ~/check_test_case.sh
                   status=$?
           else
                   # tell the caller this is untestable
                   status=125
           fi

           # undo the tweak to allow clean flipping to the next commit
           git reset --hard

           # return control
           exit $status
```

Comment: This is great, I think copying to a temp folder and back again would have worked in my example. When I say not using branches, I branch and merge often, so I end up with a very linear history. It looked like in the example they had a long running branch called `test`, which I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

`git bisect` allows to exclude specific paths, so the command simply will not be checking out commits that change that path *(except the docs is unclear on whether it will skip commits that change another path additionally to that one or not)*.

```bash
git bisect start -- ':/' ':!/dir1/' ':!/dir2/'
```

Here I use "pathspec" to first include everything in the repo and then I exclude top-level `dir1` and `dir2`.

The first `':/'` that includes everything is mandatory in this case because these parameters determine dirs to be included *(and `!` inverts the logic)*, so in absence of `':/'` git would think you didn't include anything at all and you'll get a `No testable commit found.` error.